# How do I use formatstring to print out a string?

Tags: c, security, format-string

I'm going through tutorials on formatstring vulnerabilities to learn how to code more securely. The program I've written so far is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char text[100];
    strcpy(text, argv[1]);

    printf(text);
}
```

I'm running it like this:

```
>>> ./foo $(ruby -e 'print "AAAA" + "%08x."*9 + "%x"')
AAAAffe466f4.00000001.f763b1c9.ffe458df.ffe458de.00000000.ffe459c4.ffe45964.00000000.41414141
```

I can see the "41414141" at the end, which is the AAAA at the beginning of the string. However, when I use "%s" instead like so:

```
>>> ./foo $(ruby -e 'print "AAAA" + "%08x."*9 + "%s"')
```

I get a segfault. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that at this point, you reach raw AAAA on the stack; however, the `%s` specifier expects a *pointer* to a string, i.e. the address of your AAAA, instead. There is no format string specifier for what you want to do as in the normal course of execution you wouldn't have a string pasted directly as **printf()**'s parameter; one idea would be `%c%c%c%c` to at least print the data as characters instead of hex values, but that will not work either as the smallest size of a parameter in C is an **int** and even the `%c` specifier works with **int**-sized parameter memory region.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now, I'm trying:
    ./foo $(ruby -e 'print "\x7f\x2a\x96\xff" + "%08x."*9 + "%s"')

but I'm still getting a segfault. This should be a valid pointer to a string, I think, I modified the program to print out the address of a variable. Does it have to do with 64bit addresses being longer?

Comment: I think your problem now is *endianity* - try reversing the order of bytes of the pointer.

Comment: Ahh, it's not endianity, it's stack randomization. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's generally undefined behaviour to use `printf` on a dynamic string, since you can't guarantee that the string isn't free of format specifiers. The correct thing is to say,

```
printf("%s", text);
```

or just

```
puts(text);
```

Now, that said, your first example comes down to `printf("%x%x");`. This is of course UB, but the two `%x` specifiers just make you read a bounded amount off the stack (two words), which will print garbage, but only a finite amount.

On the other hand, when you say `printf("%s")`, the function expects a *pointer to a null-terminated* sequence of bytes in a memory region which you do not control! Essentially, the function will read one word off the stack, pretend it is a pointer, and read the memory pointed to by that value -- which will almost certainly cause a segmentation fault, since you aren't allowed to access most memory addresses by default. And even if the address points into memory you're allowed to access, there's no reason there should be a zero byte coming up soon, and so you may well just run off the page and into illegal memory.

Answer (score 0):

In `test` you have at the end `%s`. `printf` expects a `char`-pointer when it encounters a `%s` but you don't provide any --> segfault. Use `puts` instead or `printf("%s", test);`

```
$ ruby -e 'print "AAAA" + "%08x."*9 + "%x"'
AAAA%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%x

$ ruby -e 'print "AAAA" + "%08x."*9 + "%s"'
AAAA%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%s
```

Both strings are invalid for `printf` because you are not passing the arguments required.